# How to access enum within struct model? Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift4

I wanted to display in my tableView the data and time which is within the struct model right now.

I tried accessing view the main, WeatherModel struct but there is a [List] which abandons me accessing the dtTxt. I just want to show the data in every row. Any help would be appreciated. I add my contents below.

Controller:

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

var weatherData = [WeatherModel]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getJSONData {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return weatherData.count

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    cell.textLabel?.text = weatherData[indexPath.row].city.name.capitalized // Instead of city name, it should be dtTxt.
    return cell
}
```

Here is my model:

```
struct WeatherModel: Codable {
   let list: [List]
   let city: City
}

struct City: Codable {
   let name: String
}

struct List: Codable {
   let main: Main
   let weather: [Weather]
   let dtTxt: String // I want to show this

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case main, weather
      case dtTxt = "dt_txt" //access here
   }
}

struct Main: Codable {
   let temp: Double
}

struct Weather: Codable {
   let main, description: String
 }
```

And here is my JSON object:

```
      {
       "list": [
        {
        "main": {
            "temp": 277.12
        },
        "weather": [{
            "main": "Clouds",
            "description": "scattered clouds"
        }],
        "dt_txt": "2018-06-05 15:00:00"
    },
        {
        "main": {
            "temp": 277.12
        },
        "weather": [{
            "main": "Sunny",
            "description": "Clear"
        }],
        "dt_txt": "2018-06-05 18:00:00"
    },
        {
        "main": {
            "temp": 277.12
        },
        "weather": [{
            "main": "Rain",
            "description": "light rain"
        }],
        "dt_txt": "2018-06-05 21:00:00"
    }
],
"city": {
    "name": "Bishkek"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[List]` contains an array of forecast objects at different times.

Use a `for` loop:

```
for forecast in weatherModel.list {
    print(forecast.dtTxt)
}
```

or filter one object by a certain condition:

```
if let threePMForecast = weatherModel.list.first(where: { $0.contains("15:00") }) {
    print(threePMForecast.dtTxt)
}
```

Comment: yeah, but why it shows only one date & time? I need all of them.

Comment: The first suggestion is supposed to print all dates.

Comment: Then the reason must be somewhere else. I tested the code in my OpenWeatherMap environment. The code print all dates. Maybe you should use `.list` as the data source array.

Comment: If you don't want to show City Name, then your dataSource must be `[List]` , and then list[indexPath.row].dt_txt would solve your problem. 

If you want to still show the City name and the dt_txt , then

`weatherData[indexPath.row].list.first.dt_txt  `